# openerp - wizard should not close on button click

Tags: button, odoo, wizard, destroy

I have added a button on wizard "Change Standard Price(stock.change.standard.price)". It is accessible from Products-> Procurement Tab -> "- update" link.

As soon as I click on that button wizard get closed though I don't want to close it. It should be close when I click on "Apply" or "cancel".

Here is the code:

Button:

```
<button string="New Cost" name="get_price" type="object" class="oe_inline"/>
```

Method:

```
def get_price(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    cost_price = 100
return {'new_price': cost_price, 'nodestroy': True}
```

I am returning nodestroy too as I read it will for not destroying wizard.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you should return the dictionary like this to reopen the wizard,

```
view_id = self.pool.get('ir.ui.view').search(cr,uid,[('model','=','your wizard')])
return {
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
    'res_model': 'your wizard',
    'name': _('Your wizard Heading'),
    'res_id': ids[0],
    'view_type': 'form',
    'view_mode': 'form',
    'view_id': view_id,
    'target': 'new',
     'nodestroy': True,
     'context': context
        }
```

Comment: I don't want to reopen i just don't want to close it.

Comment: @Pooja: it wont reopen, it will not close unless you click on X button, or special="cancel" button.

Comment: @ashif: you dont have to calculate view_id and pass that , it will work without that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to return dictionary like

```
    return {
        'name':_("wizard name"),
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'res_model': 'model', # your current model
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'nodestroy': True,
        'target': 'new',
        'context': {'default_fieldname': 'your value'}
    }
```

This will reopen the wizard.if you want to reopen the wizard.

Comment: hello, thanx for quick reply. I already tried it but it will call new  wizard. I want same wizard as i want to continue with that value.

Comment: Thanx for solution but the problem is while we click on update this wizard pop ups and it already comes with default cost price. I mean i don't want to override default_get and disturb regular flow.

Answer (score 0):

(Odoo 9/10)
The simplest thing to do is do avoid closing the wizard :

```
@api.multi
def null_action(self):
    return {
        "type": "set_scrollTop",
    }
```

As the type is used to call any method on the class ActionManager (javascript)

It's better than "type": "ir.actions.do_nothing" which generate an exception (this attribute doesn't exist)